# How to remove word length less than 2 and greater than 15

Tags: python-3.x, string

I want to remove the words which are of length less than or equal to 2 and greater than 15.

```py
    st='am is are was were be being been i do no it'
    ls=st.split(' ')
    for i in ls:
        if len(i)<=2:
            ls.remove(i)
    ls
    ['is', 'are', 'was', 'were', 'being', 'been', 'do', 'it']
```

This code is not removing 2 letter word if they are consecutive. please help me which works for all cases

Comment: `[word for word in st.split() if 15 < len(word) >=3]`

Comment: please use a code block inside your question so we can read the code more clearly

Comment: @blissweb I am new to stackoverflow, I did not understand what you mean, please let me know how to do what you said. thank you

Comment: @mama looks like someone already did it for you.  You highlight a block of text and hit the {} icon in the editor and it will make it look pretty formatted code.

Comment: @GrajdeanuAlex  maybe add it as an answer then you can be accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the Problem is that you cannot remove an item from a list while iteration through it.

A solution could be to create another list:

```
st='am is are was were be being been i do no it'
ls=st.split(' ')
ls2 = []
for i in ls:
    if not len(i)<=2 and not len(i) > 15:
        ls2.append(i)
print(l2)
# output ['are', 'was', 'were', 'being', 'been']
```